# Call method inside lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I want to call a method of my class inside a lambda expression:

```
void my_class::my_method(my_obj& obj)
{
}


void my_class::test_lambda()
{ 
   std::list<my_obj> my_list;

   std::for_each(my_list.begin(), my_list.end(), [](my_obj& obj)
   {
      // Here I want to call my_method:
      // my_method(obj);
   });
}
```

How can I do?

Comment: details are needed. Where is the for_each code, in another member function of my_class? Is my_method a static or non-static function? If it's not static and `for_each` is being not in a my_class member function, then what instance do you want to be calling the my_method on? Does it matter?

Comment: The for_each is inside another non-static member function of my_class. Why downvote?

Comment: because the question isn't clear as written.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to capture `this`, either explicitly or implicitly:

```
std::for_each(l.begin(), l.end(),
    [this](my_obj& o){ // or [=] or [&]
      my_method(o); // can be called as if the lambda was a member
    });
```

Comment: assuming that the lambda is being used from a member function of my_class. The question's not specific enough to tell if this is the case.

Comment: @bames: I think it is, the comment inside the lambda indicate that it should be called as `my_method(o)`, but I can see where you're coming from.

Comment: @Xeo You can use an alias to avoid to "pollute" all the scope with the `this` variables like this: `[self = this]`, then inside the lambda you need to refer explicitly to the this variables / functions that you want to access like: `self->my_method(o);`, I believe this is a safer way to capture the `this`, since you always need to be explicit for the accesses.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a non-static method without an object to call it on.

Make a `my_class` object and capture a reference to it in the lambda...

```
my_class x;

std::for_each(my_list.begin(), my_list.end(), [&x](my_obj& obj)
//                                            ^^^^
{
    // Here I want to call my_method:
    x.my_method(obj);
});
```

Or, if you meant the lambda was in a method of `my_class` then capture `this`.
Or, if it's a static method then you can call `my_class::my_method(obj)` without capturing anything, like bames53 said below.

Comment: and if it is a static method then you can call it without an instance: `[](my_obj &obj) { my_class::my_method(obj); }`. The question's not specific enough for us to know if it's static or not.