# gcc fails to compile generic lambda with this capture

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, this, c++14

I cannot compile the following program with gcc 6.1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

class Foo
{
public:
    void apply() const
    {
        std::for_each(std::cbegin(bars_), std::cend(bars_), [this] (const auto& x) { print(x); });
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::string> bars_;

    void print(const std::string& x) const
    {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo {};
    foo.apply();
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

```
error: cannot call member function 'void Foo::print(const string&) const' without object
         std::for_each(std::cbegin(bars_), std::cend(bars_), [this] (const auto& x) { print(x); });
                                                                                      ^~~~~
```

- Changing `const auto& x` to `const std::string& x` makes the program compile.
- Changing `print(x)` to `this->print(x)` makes the program compile.
- All versions compile with Clang (Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)).

Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Couldn't this be because a generic lambda is just a `template` function pretending not to be a `template` function, and you must qualify `this->` similarly in real template functions too? IIRC...

Comment: @underscore_d That's for dependent bases.

Comment: clang compiles it, maybe its gcc bug, see here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61636

Answer (score 5):

This is a documented [**gcc bug**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67274) which as of August 2016 has not been fixed yet.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think the compiler is obliged to deduce the type being passed to the lambda inside the for_each function, bear in mind this function has already been compiled, how can the compiler know what the for_each function is going to pass to the lambda after it passed the lambda in?

Comment: Well, it hasn't been compiled, because there's an error that blocks compilation. But I see what you're getting at. As the 3rd argument can be any callable, it seemed to me and I think you that its argument could be deducible from the input iterators, but the rest of its type couldn't. However, that just seems to be a limitation in our understanding, because `clang` accepts it, and the linked Bugzilla implies it's a valid case suffering from ambiguity in the `g++` parser.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the for_each function has already been compiled.

Comment: It certainly looks like a bug, the error
error: cannot call member function 'void Foo::print(const string&) const' without object

implies it correctly deduced the parameter type

Comment: The compiler instantiates the `for_each` with the given template parameter, which then causes instantiation of the lambda with the correct type.

Comment: @interjay OMG OFC it does, how could I have forgotten/not noticed for_each is a template function! Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

I don't know why. But the solution is to specify which print it should use:
`std::for_each(std::cbegin(bars_), std::cend(bars_), [this] (const auto& x) { this->print(x); });`

With this it compiles.
See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1177b09a3e5863e2

Comment: This is not an answer. The question already explicitly states that adding `this->` makes this compile.

Comment: than look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284059/call-method-inside-lambda-expression or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940259/lambdas-require-capturing-this-to-call-static-member-function

Comment: This is still irrelevant. The code in the question already explicitly captures `this`.